# MudForm validation on multiple tabs

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have multiple tabs with a form inside.

```
<MudTabs Elevation="4" Rounded="true" Centered="true" Color="@Color.Primary">
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formA.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formA.form?.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm @ref="formA" model="formA.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formB.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formB.form.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm @ref="formB" model="formB.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formC.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formC.form.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm  @ref="formC" model="formC.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudButton OnClick="ValidateForms" >ValidateForms</MudButton>
</MudTabs>
```

```
    public async Task ValidateForms(){
        bool isValid = true;
        isValid &= await formA.Validate();
        isValid &= await formB.Validate();
        isValid &= await formC.Validate();
        if(isValid){
            // Continue
        }
    }
```

```
    public async Task<bool> Validate()
    {
        await form.Validate();
        return form.IsValid;
    }
```

I would like to validate all forms at once and display the correspondending tab in a red border if any validation error occurs. And if switching tabs the fields should be marked as errors.
But it seems like if a form (or its fields) isn't rendered, the validation automatically succeeds. It is working for the activated tab.

Snippet: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEcRlmbbTAGxcXkw

As a workaround I could add Properties to the FormModel i.e. NameHasErrors and handle everything manually, which works. But I'd like to keep the code simpler.

Is there a straightforward method? Or do I have to use the workaround?

Comment: maybe just validate when the tab gets focus? what is the usecase for this working this way?

Comment: The user can create multiple orders for a project. This is aswell in the process of creating a project. In my opinion it's easier for the user to create and manage a project this way.
The form inside the tabpanel is rather large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `KeepPanelsAlive` to true.

From [MudBlazor docs](https://mudblazor.com/api/tabs#properties)

> If true, render all tabs and hide (display:none) every non-active.

```html
<MudTabs KeepPanelsAlive="true" Elevation="4" Rounded="true" Centered="true" Color="@Color.Primary">
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formA.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formA.form?.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm @ref="formA" model="formA.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formB.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formB.form.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm @ref="formB" model="formB.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudTabPanel Text="@formC.model.Name" Style="@GetRed(formC.form.Errors.Any())">
        <CustomForm  @ref="formC" model="formC.model" />
    </MudTabPanel>
    <MudButton OnClick="ValidateForms" >ValidateForms</MudButton>
</MudTabs>
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cYwdPcvFThBekiUo)